# Link math library with make

Tags: c, math, gcc, hyperlink

I'm using gcc version 4.8.4 on Ubuntu.
In my university assignment I have to write a function in C that converts a string that contains a number into an octal/decimal number.
That's no problem, but using the pow function makes problems.
I know that you have to link the math library when compiling, but we are given a makefile, so my professor wants us to use make.
Now, the thing is, the linking of the math library isn't included in the make file and I didn't find any way to make it work.
In the end I ended up writing my own pow function to make it work.
So my question is, is there a way to link the math library when using the make instruction, and if there is, how do you do it?

Comment: What does the make file look like? Are you allowed to edit it? Is the use of the power function unavoidable or just the most immediate solution (e.g., instead of using the Horner scheme for polynomial evaluation)?

Comment: First, using `pow` in such an assignment is usually not what you want, there are much simpler ways to deal with this. Then linking with math is to add `-lm` to the linker, usually you can do that by setting the environment varlalble `LDFLAGS` to that.

Comment: ... but note that if you are expected to use the makefile as-is, then you're out of luck.  You *can* set variables on the `make` command line or in its environment that `make` will then use, but you cannot rely on the grader to do that when your assignment is evaluated.

Comment: Most likely your prof does not want you to use floating point for integer arithmetics. He would be right, that is a bad idea. And there is absolutely no need  to use `pow`.

Comment: @LutzL I rewrote the program using the horner scheme now, and it works and made the program a lot shorter. I assume this is what was wanted. We were indeed not allowed to edit anything apart from the code of the function. Thanks for the answers!